# Getting 'configure' script to see that a package is installed

Tags: linux, compilation, package

I'm trying to re-compile gnome-packagekit (a recent update to CentOS removed it, and reinstalling it resulted in a broken application).  When I tried to run the `./configure` script, I get the following error:

```
...
checking for PACKAGEKIT... no
configure: error: Package requirements (packagekit-glib2 >= 0.7.0) were not met:

No package 'packagekit-glib2' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PACKAGEKIT_CFLAGS
and PACKAGEKIT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

According to the Software Installer, the following was installed by CentOS:

```
Compatibility package with PackageKit 0.8 libraries
compat-libpackagekit-glib2-16-0.8.9-1.el7 (64-bit)
```

but entering this (and multiple variations):

```
# yum info compat-libpackagekit-glib2
```

returns messages of:

```
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Also, running the `whereis` command results in a blank result (I assume that means the package was not found).  Lengthy Internet searches have yielded no relevant answers.

So, my questions are:

1. How do I find out where this package is, what name is it using, etc.?
2. What values do I need to specify for the environment variables (shown above) for the `./configure` script so I can re-compile gnome-packagekit?